# Finding adjoints of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

I’m going through Linear Algebra Done Right, learning about singular value decomposition. I’m a bit lost when trying to calculate an adjoint of an operator. Obviously, this is simple when you are given an operator in matrix form. My question pertains to example 7.50:

Define operator $T$ on $F^4$ by $Tz = (0, 3z1, 2z2, 3z4)$. Find $T^*Tz$. ($T^*$ being the adjoint of operator $T$). How do you show $T^*Tz = (9z1, 4z3, 0, 9z4)$?

And exercise 7D.1:

Similarly, define operator $T$ on vector space $V$. Let $u$, $x$ belong to $V$, where $u \neq 0$. $T = \langle v, u\rangle x$. How do you show $T^*T = ||x||^2 \langle v, u\rangle u$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Look at the rules of publishing questions here and please use $$ instead of ``.

Comment: Write $T$ in matrix form.  Then you will see it right away.

Comment: In the last line, did you mean $Tv = \langle u,v\rangle x$?  Similarly, what did you mean by $T^* T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that for any $(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4) \in \mathbf F^4$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
\langle T^*T(z_1,z_2,&z_3,z_4), (w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4) \rangle \\
&= \langle T(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4), T(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4) \rangle \\
&= \langle (0,3z_1,2z_2,-3z_4), (0,3w_1,2w_2,-3w_4) \rangle \\
&= 9z_1w_1 + 4z_2w_2 + 9z_4w_4 \\
&= \langle (9z_1,4z_2,0,9z_4), (w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4) \rangle
\end{align}
$$
and then $T^*T(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4) = (9z_1,4z_2,0,9z_4)$.

On the other hand, for any $w \in V$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
\langle w,T^*Tv \rangle &= \langle Tw,Tv \rangle \\
&= \langle \langle w,u \rangle x, \langle v,u \rangle x \rangle \\
&= \langle w,u \rangle \langle v,u \rangle \|x\|^2 = \langle w,\overline{\langle v,u \rangle \|x\|^2}u \rangle
\end{align}
$$
and then $T^*Tv = \overline{\langle v,u \rangle \|x\|^2}u$.